# Pktgen setting up environment and running not working as header files are missing

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel, dpdk

I'm trying to setup Pktgen according to the [Getting started with Pktgen guide](https://pktgen-dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) in my VirtualBox which is running Ubuntu 22.04.1, Pktgen 22.04.01 and DPDK 22.11.1. But for some reason I don't understand, the command in the guide - `./app/pktgen -l 0-4 -n 3 -- -P -m "[1:3].0, [2:4].1` (which is suppose to start pktgen), does not work for me as I have nothing called `pktgen` in the app folder. And when I try to run `gcc -o pktgen pktgen.c` I get several errors as  header files cannot be found, for example there is no directory or file for `pg_delay.h`.

To give some further clarification I will describe what I have done so far so if there is something glaringly wrong, it will perhaps be easier to point out.

First of I have hugepages support added.

The instructions says to run `./run.py -s default` to setup the environment. So, I have setup so that I have one network device using a DPDK-compatible driver:

[image: dpdk-compatible]

Then I have configured the `default.cfg` to run with my device and driver:

[image: default.cfg]

Then I run `./tools/run.py -s default` and get this output.

```
/tools/run.py -s default 
>>> sdk 'None', target 'None' 
<module 'cfg' from 'cfg/default.cfg'> 
Setup DPDK to run 'pktgen' application from cfg/default.cfg file
```

Not sure if this is how it is suppose to look after your run it, as it does not seem to confirm that it worked.

I then add the environment variables:

```
export RTE_SDK=home/.../mypathtodpdk
export RTE_TARGET=x86_64-native-linux-gcc
```

Finally I run `sudo -E ./app/pktgen -l 0-4 -n 3 -- -P -m "[1:3].0, [2:4].1"`, but then run into the error as described above, that is that there are header files missing and pktgen does not exist in the `app` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look under the **build** directory.  There will be another 'app' folder inside there.  In future cases like this, you can use the `find` command to find the `pktgen` executable, e.g. `find -name "pktgen"`  I think you can also install pktgen and then use it from anywhere (without ./app preceding it).  In fact, this config file appears to list pktgen as being in either /usr/local/bin or ./usr/local/bin.  You can either change that to match where it is or install it.

A couple other things to note:

- it looks like you should be using "vfio-pci" in your default.cfg, since that is what is listed in your `dpdk-devbind.py -s` output.
- In the 'map' section, those core listings that end in .0, .1, .2, etc. are assigning cores those cores to those devices.  Since you only have one device listed under 'devices', only the ones mapped from .0 will apply, so you could delete the others from 'map' and 'cores' if you run into trouble.  The other core listings may be very high, unless you 32 cores in your VM.

Comment: Of course, thanks! I'm wondering about your comment about using "vfio-pci", as in the output it says the driver is uio_pci_generic and that vfio-pci is unused so shouldn't it be uio_pci_generic? I have changed the default.cfg so it's only using 'map': ('[3:4].0'), but  I'm running into some issues when executing "./app/pktgen -l 3-4 -n 3 -- -P -m "[3:4].0" where it says "Illegal instruction". Is there something wrong with this command?

Comment: I also added  'app_path': ('/home/evorphi/Documents/Pktgen-DPDK/build/app/pktgen',), which is the directory to my pktgen binary

Comment: Those arguments say
EAL parameters: 1) use lcores 3-4 for the whole program, 2) use 3-channel memory
PktGen parameters: 1) enable promiscuous mode, 2) use cores 3/4 for rx/tx on port 0
By default it assigns your lowest lcore to be your primary lcore, which can't be use for a port's rx/tx, so I would change to using ,e.g.  -l 2-4 instead of -l 3-4.  Since you're in a VM, I'm not sure how -n 3 (memory channels) will affect things and may simply omit that to get started.